# integration and simplification trouble

Tags: calculus, integration

I have this function:

$$\pi(\theta|\vec{x}) = \frac{2^{-n/2-2}\theta^{-n/2-3}\left(\sum_\limits{i = 1}^{n} x_i^2+4\right)^{n/2+2}\exp\left({-{\left(\sum_\limits{i = 1}^{n} x_i^2  + 4\right)}/{2\theta}}\right)}{\Gamma(n/2 +2)} $$

and I am trying to take the mean of it with respect to $\theta$.

Here is what I did:

$$E(\theta|\vec{x}) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \theta \, \frac{2^{-n/2-2}\theta^{-n/2-3}\left(\sum_\limits{i = 1}^{n} x_i^2+4\right)^{n/2+2}\exp\left({-{\left(\sum_\limits{i = 1}^{n} x_i^2  + 4\right)}/{2\theta}}\right)}{\Gamma(n/2 +2)} d\theta$$
Using wolfram alpha, the answer came out to be
$$=\frac{n (\sum_{i = 1}^{n} x_i^2  + 4)\Gamma(n/2)}{4 \Gamma(n/2+2)}$$

When I simplified this by hand, I got:

$$ = \frac{n (\sum_{i = 1}^{n} x_i^2  + 4)\Gamma(n/2)}{4 (n/2+2)(n/2+1)\Gamma(n/2)} = \frac{n (\sum_{i = 1}^{n} x_i^2  + 4)}{(n+4)(n+2)}$$

However, wolfram showed that the simplification was:
$$= \frac{(\sum_{i = 1}^{n} x_i^2  + 4)}{(n+2)}$$
which is not equivalent to the original answer to the integral when plugging numbers in.

Any suggestion on where things might be going wrong would be much appreciated. The answer I obtained from the integral and the hand simplification apparently are not correct.

Comment: Call $Y = \sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2 + 4$ and try to fit it in a known distribution so you get the answer straight (probably chi-squared or gamma)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that $$\Gamma\left(x+1\right)=x\Gamma\left(x\right)$$

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\frac{n\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2+4\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)}{4\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}+2\right)}}
> &=\frac{n\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2+4\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)}{4\left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)}\\
> &=\frac{n\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2+4\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)}{4\left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2+4}{n+2}}
> \end{align*}
>   in accordance with Wolfram Alpha.